# Adding view dynamically to RecyclerView Android issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, parent-child

I have gone through a lot of similar questions on SO, but none of them helped. Iam getting the following error with my following code:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call `removeView()`
>   on the child's parent first.

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layoutParent"
    android:background="@color/AppBackground"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Event Date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtEventDate"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layoutChild"
        android:background="@color/AppBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my Recycler adapter, as follows:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            CustomViewHolder vh = holder as CustomViewHolder;
            var data = result1.ElementAt(position);
       if(mDate.Day != DateTime.MinValue.Day && mDate.Month != DateTime.MinValue.Month)
                    {
                        vh.txtEventDate.Text = mDate.ToString("dd MMMM");
                        foreach(var mdata in data.Items)
                        {
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                            lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignLeft);
                            lp.TopMargin = 10;


                            if (mdata.Birthdate.Day == mDate.Day && mdata.Birthdate.Month == mDate.Month)
                            {

                                txtNewBday = new TextView(Activity);
                                txtNewAnniversary = new TextView(Activity);
                                txtNewBday.Text = mdata.EmployeeName + "'s" + " " + "Birthday";
                                txtNewBday.LayoutParameters = lp;
                                txtNewBday.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#3B99BA"));
                                txtNewBday.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 18);
                                if (txtNewBday.Parent != null)
                                {
                                    ((ViewGroup)txtNewBday.Parent).RemoveView(txtNewBday);
                                    vh.layoutChild.AddView(txtNewBday);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    vh.layoutChild.AddView(txtNewBday);
                                }
                            }
                            if (mdata.Anniversary.Day == mDate.Day && mdata.Anniversary.Month == mDate.Month)
                            {
                                txtNewAnniversary.Text = mdata.EmployeeName + "'s" + " " + "Anniversary";
                                txtNewAnniversary.LayoutParameters = lp;
                                txtNewAnniversary.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#00525A"));
                                txtNewAnniversary.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 18);

       ERROR ****Here the previous views are removed on scroll.****
       ***Doing just vh.layoutChild.AddView(txtAnniversary) gives me the Error mentioned in the question.***
                                if (txtNewAnniversary.Parent != null)
                                {
                                    ((ViewGroup)txtNewAnniversary.Parent).RemoveView(txtNewAnniversary);
                                    vh.layoutChild.AddView(txtNewAnniversary);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    vh.layoutChild.AddView(txtNewAnniversary);
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    }
}


public override void OnViewRecycled(Java.Lang.Object holder)
        {
            base.OnViewRecycled(holder);
            CustomViewHolder vh = holder as CustomViewHolder;
            vh.layoutChild.RemoveAllViews();
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
           itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.calendar_event_row, parent, false);

            // Create a ViewHolder to hold view references inside the CardView:
            CustomViewHolder vh = new CustomViewHolder(itemView, OnClick);
            return vh;
        }
```

With this method, if I just do `vh.layoutChild.AddView(txtNewAnniversary)` I get the error mentioned in the question. If I call `RemoveView()` before adding the view, the `txtNewAnniversary` view disappear on scroll.

How can I solve this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to write this vh.layoutChild.removeAllViews() just after creating CustomViewHolder vh = holder as CustomViewHolder object

Comment: Add text view in first in Linerlayout or relative layout and then add that layout to  "layoutChild"

Comment: @JayShah do you mean in the OnViewRecycled() ?

Comment: @MaheshSuthar can you please elaborate with an example

Comment: @MaheshSuthar I tried it and still gives me the same error